# How to understand the per-gate computation overhead of the FHE scheme?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In BGV12(Fully Homomorphic Encryption without bootstapping), they investigate the efficiency of a FHE scheme by considering the *per-gate computation overhead* of the FHE scheme, defined as the ratio between the time it takes to compute a circuit homomorphically to the time it takes to compute it in the clear. I wanna know what means compute a circuit *homomorphically* and compute it *in clear*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One spends an addition time to evaluate circuit homomorphically because of scaling and modulus switching (in the case of BGV scheme). In general case, one also spends an addition time because of similar reasons.